# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, forms

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll**

Additional information: **Cannot access a disposed object.**

I am a newbie in c# and have just started working with threads. I am facing a hard time while closing a form as it keeps throwing above exception.

I am using two forms Form1 and Form2. I am doing some processing and **I need to close Form2 if conditions are met ineed to close the form2. I am using STA thread for opening the form.**

I have tried to stop the thread beforeclosing the form [**followed this link**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.90).aspx) but that didnot slove my issue. The code works fine for 5-6 times then it crashes throwing exception.

I understand the **exception occurs because I am trying to close the form** while the thread keeps running in the background. How can I close this STA thread gracefully. Here is my code:

```
private  void runBrowserThread(bool markerFound)
        {

            try
            {

                var th = new Thread(() =>
                {

                    if (markerFound == true)
                    {

                        if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<webForm>().Count() == 0)
                          //  Application.OpenForms.OfType<webForm>().First().Show();
                        {
                         webForm frm = new webForm();
                         frm.Show();
                         }

                        Application.Run();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<webForm>().Count() == 1)
                        {
                            Form fc = Application.OpenForms["webForm"];

                            if (fc != null)
                                //  _shouldStop = true;

                                fc.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { fc.Close(); }));
                        }

                    }

                });
                th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                th.Start();


            }
            catch (ThreadInterruptedException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: You need to stop creating forms on a worker thread.  If you don't then you get to debug *much* harder problems than this one.  [This one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx).  Nobody knows how to do that.  And, as usual, you don't explain why you think you need to do this so nobody can offer a better alternative.

Comment: @ Hans Passant: I would like to apologise if I am being too vague here..Actually I am working on video capturing application form 1 captures the video and processes its frames ,If the required frame is found then I need to open form2   else I need to close it if its already open.

Comment: I am using a thread class for frame processing and to open or close forms from that thread class I need to use worker threads